# vb web site not showing correctly on install on IIS7

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I have software running on a windows pc see link below

http://3dweb.myftp.biz/ISS_SNG_WEB/WebISS/login.aspx

i have now installed the same software on a vps system see below

http://3dwebvps.myftp.biz/tw/WebISS/login.aspx

It does not seem to be using either the CSS or Masterpages.

any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look and your browser console output during second side load

Comment: Sorry, Yuriy - what does that mean?

Comment: It shows things like *"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain"*. Make sure web server is configured correctly to serve these file types

Comment: I still can't get this to work, should I be able to see the css file when I type it into the address bar?  I dont understand why its not working

Comment: Make sure (ask your host) to serve the files with correct MIME type. E.g. if it's a .CSS i server should serve it as stylesheet, not plain text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my VPS, Windows Server IIS 7
I needed to install Static Content under Roles Services.  Now appears to be working lovely.
Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet is loading as expected

[image]

but seems to be empty. When I browse to http://3dwebvps.myftp.biz/tw/WebISS/Styles.css I get an empty file

[image]

Comment: the file is in the following location C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TW\WebISS\Styles.css

Comment: What do the file contain if you open it in an editor?

Comment: it contains the full css info as expected

Comment: Well the css file that is loading contains nothing, so I would guess that the file you opened is not the one being used by your application.

Comment: when i viewed the link from the source it linked to the correct file - strange